# Passing data between usercontrols

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm with a problem here.

I have a DB table `Things(id,name,description)`.

In default.aspx i do a "select name from Things" to SqlDataReader, then i bind it to a Listbox.

So now i have a listbox with all names from Things.

What i want to do is: when selecting a listbox row, and then clicking a button next to it, that passes all the info from that row (id,name,description) to a ListView row that it's right next to it. My problem it's when i select the listbox row, i only got the name, and i don't want to make a "select * from things where name=x" because there maybe equal names in the table.

How can i make it ?

Comment: You need to get the primary key from the table as well as the name, then you can do "select * from things where pk=x"

Answer (score 1):

Use next definition of ListBox control:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lbSample" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsSample"
    DataTextField="name" DataValueField="id"></asp:ListBox>
```

In this way you can easily get **name** property as well as **id**.

Comment: thank you. Now how can i call the id from the selected index/item on my btClick method ? listbox1.selecteditem.value does not work

Comment: You can use `lbSample.SelectedItem.Text` for "name" and `lbSample.SelectedItem.Value` for "id". Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

Simple but "dirty" solution would be to select everything from the table:

```
Select [id], [name], [description] from Things
```

Then have all those as the value of each item, separated by `|` character for example.

Now pass this value to the ListView and parse it when required, splitting by `|` to get the individual data you need. (Id, name and description)

This way you won't have to query the database again, but it's not elegant and pose risk of user "faking" data that doesn't really exist as you're relying on client side data.